# Extract Installer Package Signing Certificates from xip archive

Tags: macos, security, keychain, certificate, signature

It's possible to extract Code Signing Certificates (CSCs) from an .app or signed .dmg as ASN.1 (DER) with

```
codesign -d --extract-certificates prefix /path/to/file.dmg
```

After that you can do stuff with it using `openssl`, `security` etc.

My goal is to do the same for signed **xip archives**, which use **Installer Package Signing Certificates** (IPSCs). You can verify xip signatures with

```
pkgbuild --check-signature /path/to/archive.xip
```

But there doesn't seem to be an option to actually export the certificates the way codesign can do it with CSCs.

Is there a way to do it from the command line?

The eventual goal is to deal with xip archives that are signed with self-signed/self-issued IPSCs. It will be a script that first checks the signature with `pkgbuild`, and then, if the user wants to, it should export the certificates, and then add them to the keychain as trusted. I know you could always just dequarantine the xip file with the self-signed certificate, and this will be an additional option, but this is always on a per-file basis, so there also has to be the ability to extract the certificates (root/leaf) and import them into keychain as trusted (or trusted root). How I'll do the latter I don't know yet, but first thing's first.

Thank you for your help. (This is my first post at AskDifferent.)

Comment: I looked around a bit, and there's an app called [RB App Checker Lite](https://brockerhoff.net/RB/AppCheckerLite/) that will read the signature information from a xip archive, and also display the certificates in full. So there's surely a way to do it, but maybe not from the command line. (?)

Answer (score 3):

I think it works with the following command:

`xar --dump-toc="${HOME}/Desktop/header.xml" -f /path/to/your/archive.xip`

This will write an xml file called "header" onto your desktop, and that one contains the X509 certificates. You only need to parse it; maybe `jq` will do the job best.

**Edit:** however, `jq` isn't native macOS, so it has to be with xmllint etc. This below works. It will put all certificates in your home folder.

```
FILEPATH="/path/to/your/archive.xip"
FILENAME=$(/usr/bin/basename "$FILEPATH")
/usr/bin/xar --dump-toc=- -f "$FILEPATH" \
    | /usr/bin/xmllint --xpath '//signature[@style="RSA"]' - \
    | /usr/bin/sed -n '/<X509Certificate>/,/<\/X509Certificate>/p' \
    | xargs \
        | /usr/bin/awk '{ \
                gsub("<X509Certificate>","-----BEGINCERTIFICATE-----"); \
                gsub("</X509Certificate>","-----ENDCERTIFICATE-----"); \
                print}' \
        | /usr/bin/awk '{gsub(" ","\n"); print}' \
        | /usr/bin/awk '{ \
                gsub("BEGINCERTIFICATE-----","BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"); \
                gsub("-----ENDCERTIFICATE","\n-----END CERTIFICATE"); \ 
                print}' \
    | /usr/bin/csplit -k -s -n 1 -f "$FILENAME"-cert - '/END CERTIFICATE/+1' '{3}' 2>/dev/null
for CERT in *"-cert"* ; do
    if [[ $(/bin/cat "$CERT") == "" ]] ; then
        rm -rf "$CERT"
    else
        mv "$CERT" "$CERT.pem"
    fi
done
```